# Why does controller see {{ data.binder }} while UI sees 'data'?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I'm trying to use angularfire's `$remove`, but my controller is getting the `{{ data.binder }}` instead of the data value:

My controller code is very simple:

```
 $scope.removeResponse = function(id){
        console.log(id);
        $scope.responses.$remove(id);
    }
```

(`$scope.responses` declared elsewhere.)

HTML:

```
 <td>[<a  data-ng-click="removeResponse('{{ response.$id }}')" >Delete</a>]</td>
```

When I look at the element in console, I see this:

```
<a data-ng-click="removeResponse('-JC8IN82_zp1Vwr6u-oo')">Delete</a>
```

But when I run the code, the function `removeResponse` logs this value for `id`:

```
{{ response.$id }} responsescontroller.js:93
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "{{ response.$id }}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at Error (<anonymous>)
```

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<a data-ng-click="removeResponse(response.$id)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the click event handler the expression `removeResponse('{{ response.$id }}')` is evaluated. `'{{ response.$id }}'` is a string literal and passed to the `removeResponse()` function as such.

If you want the actual id then you need

```
<a data-ng-click="removeResponse(response.$id)">
```

`removeResponse('-JC8IN82_zp1Vwr6u-oo')` is the rendered HTML, which seems strange, but that's how it works.